# Teechart GDI object consumption

Tags: activex, teechart

My Application Currently Crashes as soon the GDI object count reaches to 8800,IS there any way or setting I need to do  so that the consumption of GDI by TeeChart Can be less.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the limit of your GDI objects in your Ms Windows configuration
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx

But, as you indicated in your question, you should reduce their use. I had some problems with GDI objects when changing the format of a huge number of cells on a grid. You could try not changing many colors or fonts in your chart.

Comment: Actually in Our application user is plotting around 100 charts after that the application was crashing in 32 bit so we decided to move to 64 bit and changed the Charting tool to TeeChart thinking this will consume less GDI object but the impact is same.

Comment: Also our Application will be used by a user who don't have access to the registry so we can't increment the limit of GDI object.

Comment: @AkshayBhalla Instead plotting 100 graphics you could try to store 100 data sets and  have only a TeeChart showing the set the user is working with. If your user needs to visualize more than one data set at the same time you can distribute the 100 data set in two o three chart, I doubt he/she will need to visualize the 100 sets at the same time.

Comment: @AkshayBhalla What is the pourpose of that? Print them? Let the user select one?

Comment: Can't change the functionality the same works fine with Graphic Server COntroller in 32 bit

Comment: Hello @AkshayBhalla Could you try to arrange a simple project for us because we can try to suggest acurate solution for you?

Comment: Can you let me know whether using OpenGL for rendering will Save the GDI object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GDI+ TeeChart canvas instead of GDI.

Comment: Tried this it won't help